# Что значит «PHP не поддерживает беззнаковые целые (integer)»?

Tags: php, числа, php-faq

В [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.integer.php) указано:

> PHP не поддерживает беззнаковые целые (integer)

Что это значит: беззнаковые целые?

---

Я предполагаю, что, например, `1` — беззнаковое; `-1` или `+1` — со знаком. Но PHP ведь адекватно работает со всеми тремя вариантами...

Comment: Просто 1 в php это все таки +1, т.е. если из 1 вычесть 2 то получите -1. А в беззнаковом типе данных минус невозможен в принципе и ведет к переполнению и 1-2 оказывается вдруг равно 4294967295 (для беззнакового 32 битного типа)

Comment: `1` - это ведь `+1`. 32 бит под `integer` даёт возможность выразить от `+2 147 483 648` до `-2 147 483 647` (старший бит под знак отводится).  Если его тоже отдать под представление числа - его [число] можно удвоить. Правда тогда все будут положительные. Итого: `uint` - от `0` до `+4 294 967 295`. В `PHP`, с его динамической типизацией, с `unsigned` не поработаешь.

Answer (score 5):

Это не вполне корректная формулировка. Правильная - такая: *"PHP не поддерживает беззнаковые целочисленные типы данных"*.

Беззнаковый целочисленный тип данных - это целочисленный тип данных, неспособный хранить отрицательные числа.

Обычно в языках программирования со статической типизацией целочисленные типы данных идут парами. Так, в C++11 есть знаковый тип `int32_t`, вмещающий числа от -2 147 483 648 до 2 147 483 647 - и парный ему беззнаковый тип `uint32_t`, вмещающий числа от 0 до 4 294 967 295.

Но в PHP, как в языке с динамической типизацией, целочисленный тип данных всего один (integer), и он знаковый.

Comment: В java нет беззнаковых тоже вроде как.

Comment: @pavel да, есть такое. Потому я и сказал - "обычно", а не "во всех" :)